# Why can't I pass an array of bytes to a routine that takes TByteDynArray?

Tags: delphi, types, parameter-passing, delphi-xe2

The documentation defines `System.Types.TByteDynArray` as:

```
type TByteDynArray = array of Byte;
```

If I create a routine like so:

```
procedure DoSomething(args: array of Byte);
begin
end;
```

and call the routine like so, there is no compilation error:

```
DoSomething([1, 2, 3]);
```

However if I change the type taken by the routine to:

```
procedure DoSomething(args: TByteDynArray);
```

Calling the function in the same way produces this compilation error:

```
[DCC Error] E2010 Incompatible types: 'TByteDynArray' and 'Set'
```

Why aren't `array of Byte` and `TByteDynArray` treated equally, as apparently they should be? My codebase heavily references `TByteDynArray` and I want to use this handy short-hand for creating such arrays instead of `TByteDynArray.Create(1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: Use open array parameters where you can since they are more flexible.

Comment: More on the subject: [Open array parameters and array of const](http://www.rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html). You are confusing open array *parameters* with dynamic array *types*. They look very similar, but they are different concepts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are dealing with two things here even though syntax looks the same.

One is called dynamic array type: `type TByteDynArray = array of Byte;` and
another is open array parameter `procedure DoSomething(args: array of Byte);`

[Open array parameter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Open_Array_Parameters) allows any array of given type to be passed to procedure, including dynamic arrays.

But when you declare `procedure DoSomething(args: TByteDynArray);` you can only pass `TByteDynArray` variable to it.

`[1, 2, 3]` is static array and it is not assignment compatible with dynamic array.

Following assignment would throw same error

```
var
  a: TByteDynArray;

a := [1, 2, 3];
```

In Delphi `[]` are also used for declaring sets so compiler thinks you are trying to assign set to dynamic array.

```
var
  s: set of byte;

  s := [1, 2, 3];
```

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer (also thanks to Heffernan for the comment)! I wasn't aware there was a difference, and I was really hoping I could do assignments that easily.

Comment: See also this link, [Open array parameters and array of const](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html), for a good description of the open array concept.

Comment: You can do it that easily if you use open array parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `is` and `as` operators to do casting and checking. Some implicit conversions can be used but the compiler warns you. This is a strength of Delphi in the long run. It lets you do that stuff, but it wont let you merrily shoot yourself in the foot with stuff that is almost--but not quite--the same unless you ask for it explicitly.

That is one of the ways Delphi tries to make stupid hard(er) to do. Learn to drive with that seat belt. It is not that much pain, and a whole lot safer.